# CGLayer appearing the wrong way around

Tags: iphone, uiview, quartz-graphics

I've got a UIView subclass (TraceView) which is 200 wide by 100 tall, and I'm attempting to draw on it pixel by pixel.  In this case, I'm trying to draw a horizontal blue line that goes 75% of the way across.  Instead, I get two vertical blue lines (one at the edge, one in the middle), that go 75% of the way up.  It seems like the CGLayer I use has been rotated 90 degrees and shrunk 50%.  What can I do to correct this?

At the top of the .m file:

```
#define WORLD_WIDTH 200
#define WORLD_HEIGHT 100
#define ABGR_BYTES 4

@implementation TraceView

int theImage[WORLD_WIDTH][WORLD_HEIGHT];
```

Overriding drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef theViewContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGLayerRef theCGLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(theViewContext, rect.size, nil);
    CGContextRef theCGLayerContext = CGLayerGetContext(theCGLayer);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(theImage, WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT, 8, WORLD_WIDTH * ABGR_BYTES, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    // is ABGR
    for(int i=0;i<150;i++) {
        theImage[i][0]=0xFFFF0000;
    }

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);   
    CGContextDrawImage(theCGLayerContext, rect, image); 
    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(theViewContext, rect, theCGLayer);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it working, silly me.

It works OK if I treat the array as theImage[y][x] rather than theImage[x][y].